# Showing the equality of three series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I have a series defined for $x\in\left]-1,1\right[$ by $$S(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}.$$ I’ve been able to show this series is pointwise convergent on $]-1,1[$ and uniformly convergent on all intervals $[a,b]\subset ]-1,1[$. I’m now trying to show that $$S(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^p x^{n(p+1)}\right) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty (-1)^p\frac{x^{p+1}}{1-x^{p+1}}$$

I have managed to prove the rightmost equality, but I can’t seem to prove that the series on the right are equal to $S(x)$. I’ve tried (in vain) to find an upper bound to the partial sums of $\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n}-(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{1-x^{n+1}}$ that would go to 0 as $n\to\infty$ but this doesn’t seem to work.

Any help/indication is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \frac  1 {1+t} =\sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{p} t^{p}$. Put $t=x^{n}$ and multiply by $x^{n}$  to get  the first equality.

Next interchange  the sums and use the formula for  a geometric sum to get the last equality.